# What's this error that occurs when I attempt to install the omnisocial gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, rubygems, omniauth

When I run bundle install after adding the omnisocial gem to my gem file, I get this when I have in fact already installed the latest version of the oa-core gem:

```
  Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "oa-core":
  In Gemfile:
    omnisocial depends on
      oa-core (~> 0.1.2)

    omniauth depends on
      oa-core (0.2.6)
```

...

```
gem install oa-core
Successfully installed oa-core-0.2.6
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for oa-core-0.2.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for oa-core-0.2.6...
```

Do I need to update my version of rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `omnisocial` gem's dependencies have not been updated to match the latest `oa-core` release. Bundler will attempt to resolve all the dependencies for all the gems.

In this situation, `omnisocial` says it is quite happy with any of the `0.1.x` releases (as long as it's the `0.1.2` release or one after that) of `oa-core` (this is what the `~>` operator means) but `omniauth` says it *must* have `0.2.6`. Obviously, `0.2.6` is *not* a part of the `0.1.x` set of releases and so you are getting this error.

`omnisocial`'s gem dependencies must be upgraded to match the latest `oa-core` version. That is the problem.

Alternatively, you could use `omniauth` which is designed to work with this latest version of the `oauth` suite, rather than using `omnisocial`.